# Find out if repository or proxy is blocking my connection

Tags: git, ssh

I have a Bitbucket repository which I'm accessing over HTTPS, through a proxy. For this, I have set up the options for `http.proxy` and `https.proxy` in Git.

Now, I've changed HTTPS to SSH.

This time, when I run `git pull` I get:

```
Repository not found
The requested repository does not exist, or you do not have permission to access it.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

If I ping the repository like this:

```
ssh -vvv git@my-repo.com
```

The connection is established, then I get:

```
Authenticated to my-repo.com ([some-ip]:7999).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug2: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x10
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 2097512 rmax 32678
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 100 id 0
shell request failed on channel 0
```

If I display the remote `git remote -v`, the answer is:

```
origin git@my-repo.com:7999/my-project.git (fetch)
origin git@my-repo.com:7999/my-project.git (push)
```

I would just like to know if this fails:

**A**.in the machine hosting the Bitbucket repository

**B**.in the proxy

Any idea of how I could find this out?

Comment: Based on the error message you get when accessing the repository via ssh, it looks like the machine hosting the repository is denying you access.  Running `ssh git@my-repo.com` is not "pinging the repository", and wouldn't tell you anything about a particular repository. The fact that ssh access is failing could simply be a wrong public key, and your ability to access the repository via ssh may not correlate with your ability to access it via `https` depending on how you have things configured.  There's really not enough information in your question for us to provide an accurate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post the whole log from

```
ssh -Tvvv git@my-repo.com
```

From the updated log, this part clearly says that the connection and authentication is ok:

```
Authenticated to my-repo.com ([some-ip]:7999).
```

The message

```
Repository not found
```

says that the authentication was successful, but the repository is not where you specified it should be. Have a look at the output of

```
git remote -v
```

and make sure that the paths on the server exists (they probably don't exist).

Your format of `remote` does not allow to specify port as described in the [manual page for git](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/). You should use the explicit `ssh://` format as follows:

```
ssh://git@my-repo.com:7999/my-project.git
```

Comment: I updated my question with a larger part of the error message.

Comment: 1) Where should be the git repository on the server. 2) What is the output of `git remote -v`

Comment: 1)The server can be accessed at `git@my-repo.com:7999/my-project.git`. 2)Same, I updated my question.

Comment: What do you mean by *The server can be accessed at git@my-repo.com:7999/my-project.git* ? The git clearly says that the repository does not exists. How do you verify it can be accessed this way? In this format, is is not possible to specif port as you can see in manual page for `git`. You should use `ssh://git@my-repo.com:7999/my-project.git`

Comment: Sorry, the repository on the server(not the server itself) can be accessed that way. I verified by looking at the repository and asking the SSH address to use for cloning and it's the same.

Comment: Why would I need the `ssh://` part? Look at this Github guide: https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/. There is no `ssh://` when setting remote repository using SSH.

Comment: Because you need to specify the port. If you have a look at the url format without `ssh://` in [manual page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/), there is no `port` field

Comment: Thank you! This relatively obscure thing took so much of my time